# How to define level tree traversal of a binary tree in isabelle/hol

Tags: binary-tree, isabelle

I have written level traversal of binary tree in other language definitions, but I don't know how to represent level traversal in isabelle/hol.Has anyone defined it or how to define it?

Comment: such as Breadth First in haskell. http://www.aryweb.nl/2013/10/28/haskell-tree-traversal/ 
OR How to formalize Breadth First in Isabelle/HOL

Answer (score 2):

In principle, you can do it exactly the same way as in Haskell. The problematic bit is that you have to prove termination of the recursive auxiliary function (what is called `tbf` in the Haskell code you linked). The easiest way to show this is by finding some sort of *measure* on the input (a list of trees) that decreases with every recursive call.

I propose the following measure: sum the sizes of all the trees in the list, where the size is the number of all the nodes in the tree (including leaf nodes).

We can use the binary trees from HOL-Library (`HOL-Library.Tree`). First, we define some auxiliary functions on trees, including our size functions, and prove some facts about them:

```
primrec tree_values :: "'a tree ⇒ 'a list" where
  "tree_values Leaf = []"
| "tree_values (Node l x r) = [x]"

primrec tree_children :: "'a tree ⇒ 'a tree list" where
  "tree_children Leaf = []"
| "tree_children (Node l x r) = [l, r]"

primrec tree_size :: "'a tree ⇒ nat" where
  "tree_size Leaf = 1" 
| "tree_size (Node l x r) = tree_size l + tree_size r + 1"

definition tree_list_size :: "'a tree list ⇒ nat"
  where "tree_list_size = sum_list ∘ map tree_size"

lemma tree_size_pos: "tree_size t > 0"
  by (induction t) auto

lemma tree_size_nonzero [simp]: "tree_size t ≠ 0"
  by (simp add: tree_size_pos)

lemma tree_list_size_children [simp]:
  "tree_list_size (tree_children t) = tree_size t - 1"
  by (cases t) (auto simp: tree_list_size_def)
```

Next, we will need another simple lemma on `sum_list` and `concat`:

```
lemma sum_list_concat: "sum_list (concat xs) =     sum_list (map sum_list xs)"
  by (induction xs) auto
```

Finally, we can define BFS and prove its termination:

```
function bfs_aux :: "'a tree list ⇒ 'a list" where
  "bfs_aux ts =
     (if ts = [] then [] else concat (map tree_values ts) @ bfs_aux (concat (map tree_children ts)))"
  by auto
termination
proof (relation "measure tree_list_size")
  fix ts :: "'a tree list"
  assume ts: "ts ≠ []"
  have "tree_list_size (concat (map tree_children ts)) =
        sum_list (map (tree_list_size ∘ tree_children) ts)"
    by (simp add: map_concat sum_list_concat tree_list_size_def o_assoc)
  also from ‹ts ≠ []› have "… < sum_list (map tree_size ts)"
    by (intro sum_list_strict_mono) (auto simp: tree_size_pos)
  also have "… = tree_list_size ts"
    by (simp add: tree_list_size_def)
  finally show "(concat (map tree_children ts), ts) ∈ measure tree_list_size"
    by simp
qed auto

definition bfs :: "'a tree ⇒ 'a list"
  where "bfs t = bfs_aux [t]‹›
```

And we can test it:

```
value "bfs (⟨⟨⟨Leaf, ''d'', Leaf⟩, ''b'', ⟨Leaf, ''e'', Leaf⟩⟩, ''a'', 
             ⟨⟨Leaf, ''f'', Leaf⟩, ''c'', ⟨Leaf, ''g'', Leaf⟩⟩⟩)"
> "[''a'', ''b'', ''c'', ''d'', ''e'', ''f'', ''g'']"
    :: "char list list"
```

For more on defining functions with non-trivial recursion patterns like this and proving their termination, see the [documentation of the function package](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2019/doc/functions.pdf) (Section 4 in particular).